# Zend query only works with backticks: When are backticks necessary

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Okay, so i have this standard query to get messages for a user

```
$s=$this->select()->where("to=?",$user->id)->orWhere("from=?",$user->id);
```

It gives a syntax error near the to.

The generated sql

```
SELECT `messages`.* FROM `messages` WHERE (to='1')
```

also gives an error in phpymysql

So I found that using backticks around the to and from makes it go away

```
$s=$this->select()->where("`to`=?",$user->id)->orWhere("`from`=?",$user->id);
```

which has me a little befuddled, since i did not need to do that in another table in the same database

```
$select=$this->select()->where("city_id=?",$city->city_id);
//Works just fine w/o backticks
```

Why is that?When are backticks really necessary? All three are INT(11) columns so where is the differentce

Comment: damn i figured this out rather quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TO` is the keyword within mysql. If we use keywords as field name then it must be enclosed within backticks to differentiate that it should not be used as keyword

Answer (score 1):

You need to use back-ticks around identifiers that are also SQL reserved words.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html for a list of reserved words in MySQL.

You also need to use back-ticks around identifiers that contain international characters, punctuation, or whitespace.  Yes, such identifiers are allowed in SQL, you just need to delimit them.